# .keyup vs .change when using a textbox search?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For my project, when I use this:

```
    $("#txtSearch").keyup(function () {
    var x = $("#txtSearch").val();
```

I am able to type into a search text box and it will take the value entered and search for whatever I have typed in.

```
@Html.TextBox("txtSearch", null, new { @placeholder = "Search for a Vehicle" })
```

However, the reason I do not want to manually type it in is because the value needs to come from whatever is clicked on in the Cascade Drop Down List.

When I use the following code to get the value from the cascade drop down list, it shows the value (ID, this is what I want to search for) in the search text box, but it does not actually search for it.

```
    $("#DDMDL").change(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").val($(this).val());
```

.........

```
                  @Html.TextBox("txtSearch", null, new { @placeholder = "Search 
                  for a Vehicle" })
```

How do I make it get the value from the cascade drop down list(ID) and then search for it as I would when I type it into the search text box? I do not understand why it does not work because it gets the correct ID but this time it does not search as it would when I change the code to .keyup to allow me to type in and it would search.

Comment: You could use `$("#txtSearch").val($(this).val()).trigger('keyup);`

Comment: Just tried it, also tried it with "onkeyup" instead of "keyup" and it doesn't work. Any other suggestion? It just shows the ID in the text field but does not search.

Comment: @StephenMuecke any idea what I can do to fix this? Really need it ASAP

Comment: If your `.keyup()` function was previously working, then using `.trigger('keyup')` will work. Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypfL2zcp/) for an example

Comment: Got help from someone on the ASP forum, if anyone needs what fixed it, they can view it here: https://forums.asp.net/t/2119439.aspx?+keyup+vs+change+when+using+a+textbox+search+   Thanks @StephenMuecke for the idea!